# Ext.field.InputMask focused by default

Tags: javascript, extjs

Ext.field.InputMask allows you to create input fields with predefined properties.
A sample is shown in this [link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/modern/Ext.field.InputMask.html). 
In the example, you need to click on the field for it to get the focus and only then you can input the data in there.

How do i make Ext.field.InputMask in that example focused by default and ready to accept keyboard input, without clicking/tab to that field?

Answer (score 1):

You can add event listener to catch `painted` event and use `focus` method on component to achieve the focus.

Just add `listeners` to field like below:

```
Ext.create({
    fullscreen: true,
    xtype: 'formpanel',

    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        label: 'Phone Number',
        placeholder: '(xxx) xxx-xxxx',
        inputMask: '(999) 999-9999',
        listeners: {
            painted: function (component) { 
                component.focus();
            }
        }
    }]
});
```